# Puppet dashboard

Tags: puppet

I saw your comment on "Puppet Dashboard replaces site.pp".  How did you link together normal /etc/puppet files with Dashboard?  I can see all my nodes in Dashboard, but Dashboard classes have nothing to do with puppet classes.  How do you link the two together?

Answer (score 1):

Puppet Dashboard can act as an [External Node Classifier](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html), applying classes to nodes.

The Enterprise dashboard seems like it's a pretty capable ENC, and the newly announced Puppet Node Manager will be its successor.

On the open source side, the Puppet Labs team has stopped supporting Dashboard, leaving support of it to the community.  For node classification when using open source, I'd recommend [using Hiera](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/complete_example.html#using-hierainclude).

If you do want to go through with setting up Dashboard's ENC alongside your current node definitions, instructions are [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/dashboard/manual/1.2/bootstrapping.html#using-dashboard-for-node-classification), but I'd highly recommend keeping all of your configuration data about nodes in one place.